# How can I help my pets to have a good birth or reincarnation?

Tags: animals, avatars

I have some cats as pets. Does chanting mantras or name of God to them make any difference in their(animals or trees) life cycle?

What are the suggested methods in helping them to think about God or get a human life sooner? Not sure whether it is even possible, does any of our scriptures discuss this? Or is it completely depending on their karma?

Comment: animals are innocent (_even carnivorous_). So they don't need to show effort for good birth or reincarnation.

Comment: Yes, chanting mantras or name of God definitely helps. Not only does it help the dear pets because of listening to the sweet and melodious name of God, but it also purifies the Atmosphere by sending out loving vibrations, not only that it also liberates us, who are chanting, and thus we also are kind, compassionate, loving and Godly. So yes, chanting definitely makes a great difference.

Comment: I believe only human beings have the capability of being spiritual

Comment: A human can only correct his deeds, rest shall happen as it happens...the pets you talk about will live their life and carry on into the next one regardless of your actions...but that should not stop you from chanting the lords name...

Comment: @Sai “ Yes, chanting mantras or name of God definitely helps. Not only does it help the dear pets because of listening to the sweet and melodious name of God, but it also purifies the Atmosphere by sending out loving vibrations, not only that it also liberates us, who are chanting, and thus we also are kind, compassionate, loving and Godly. So yes, chanting definitely makes a great difference.” <—— Wonderful ! Thx for posting this 

Answer (score 4):

Karma in Hinduism is divided into 3 kinds:

- Sanchita - Our accumlated karma, rather like a bank balance. From
  this we have
- Parabdha - The fruits of the actions we experience in this lifetime, 
  and
- Kriyamana - The karma we are accumlating in this lifetime, which will
  feed Sanchita

Since animals and plants cannot distinguish right from wrong, it is believed that they do not contribute to their kriyamana. Instead they will feel the effects of parabdha, until they are eligible for a human body again.

As for chanting holy names to influence their future birth, I'm not aware of anything in Hindu scripture that says this would have any effect. Animals are controlled by nature, and will continue in this cycle of life and death until they are ready to be human again.

Answer (score 3):

There are several instances in the history where trees/animals would get liberation by the mercy of the Lord and His devotees. We hear of these from the pastimes of Lord Caitanya, Ramanujacarya and others. Below is some relevant information from Caitanya Caritamrta:

> Sri Caitanya Mahaprabhu once asked Haridasa Ṭhakura how trees and
>   plants could be delivered, and Haridasa Ṭhakura replied that the loud
>   chanting of the Hare Krishna maha-mantra would benefit not only trees
>   and plants but insects and all other living beings

When we chant a little loud any one who hears gets benefited. Another thing is when you feed them with prasada (sanctified food that is offered to Lord Krisha/Vishnu) that will also benefit them. Having said that animals don't get karma for their actions. Karma is there only for humans because in the human birth God has given us intelligence for self realization. If a dog jumps a red light no one cares but if we do we get a ticket.

Comment: As you have mentioned in the answer, What is the story related to Ramanujacharya regarding this topic?